# using "file" and then "foreach" results in line breaks between values

Tags: php, file, foreach

I create a file with Random numbers:

```
<?php
$file = 'test.txt';
for ($i=1; $i<=100; $i++) {
$rand_num = rand(10000,20000);
file_put_contents($file, $rand_num . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

I then use "file" to read the data from the file and manipulate each line (not included in the code here). When I put again the data in the file- there is a a line break after the $value:

```
<?php
$file = 'test.txt';
$fp = fopen($file, 'rb');
$content = file($file);
file_put_contents($file, '');
foreach ($content as $value){
file_put_contents($file, $value . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

Instead of giving me:

```
190191
920191
829281
```

It give me:

```
190191

920191

829281
```

If I do something like:
$processed_line = "$value is good";

It will show:

```
190191
value is good
920191
value is good
829281
value is good
```

instead of putting the string next to $value- 190191 is good.

any idea?
Feel like Im missing something tiny and silly.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$value = trim($value, "\r\n");` as first line in your loop

the problem is because at the end of value you already have `\n` symbol

Answer (score 1):

By default, the lines inside the text file are fetched with any newlines still attached; inside your `foreach` you append another one, hence the empty lines.

You can use the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag to `file()` to leave off the newlines from each array element:

```
$content = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```